# IntelliJ error when creating file object

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea

When I try to create a file in IntelliJ, for example with the line:

```
 File f = new File("hamlet.txt");
```

I get the following error:

> File () in File cannot be applied: java.lang.String

That is the syntax everywhere, what's up with IntelliJ?

Comment: Add the whole code, please.

Comment: check your imports

Comment: Did you also check that you're using the correct Java Version? Sometimes, IntelliJ might fill in odd versions like 5.

Answer (score 1):

That was a silly question of mine. It turns out my class name was file so I was basically tampering with one of the foundational parts of Java. Thanks for your help though.